# Crystal Reports : combine and sum two fields if another field is a duplicate

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, duplicates, crystal-reports-xi

i have been having trouble for a while figuring this out. I  am looking to combine the rows that have duplicate "materials" and in doing so sum up the quantities of each and the prices.

Material   qty   unit price
a                     5         20.00
a                     5         20.00
b                      2            5.00
c                     1            5.00

and to get it like

Material   qty  unit price
a                  10       40.00
b                     2         5.00
c                     1       5.00

Ive looked and found similar questions but couldnt figure it out. sorry if its a repost.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Group based on your Material field and then insert a summary by right-clicking on your qty field -> Insert Summary.
If you can't (or don't want to) group, then you will have to create running totals to summarize your different materials.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Its been bugging me for a while. It was the summarizing that i wasn't doing and it fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Please make sure to mark the answer as answered or helpful so that other people can benefit from it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you begin creating the report, one of the first options is grouping, followed by aggregates (sum, count etc.).  Once you finish the report wizard, suppress the details and the group headers.